# How to combine multiple text files into a Hive table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am currently trying to write a Hive script to take in a directory path and generate a Hive table combining all the different files in the path together. I have found how to load files given I know the direct path to them, but how can I do this without knowing all the file paths?

This is how I would do it if I know the paths given directory, /combine:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/combine/file1.txt' INTO TABLE tablename;
LOAD DATA INPATH '/combine/file2.txt' INTO TABLE tablename;
```

But how would you get the same result if you dont know the file paths, only the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just  just `*` symbol could  load all the file under the e directory into the table  .

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/combine/*' INTO TABLE tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external Hive table.

**Create a folder on HDFS and load the two files there:**

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /hive-data
hadoop fs -put file1.txt /hive-data/file1.txt
hadoop fs -put file2.txt /hive-data/file2.txt
```

**Alternatively, specify a directory from which to load all files:**

```
hadoop fs -put directory-with-files/* /hive-data/
```

**Verify the files are loaded properly:**

```
hadoop fs -ls /hive-data
```

**Create an external table in Hive and refer to the HDFS location:**

*(Change the schema, field, and line delimiters to match your data files.)*

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tablename
(
    id INT,
    desc STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 'hdfs:///hive-data';
```

**Verify data in Hive:**

```
select * from tablename;
```